# Why is my variable empty?

Tags: php

Why is the $book variable empty? I've checked everything before it and up until that point everything is correct. I've even tried renaming it but that didn't work :(

```
<?php
$postContactUrl = 'https://apiconnector.com/v2/contacts/';
 $data = array(
'Email' => $_GET['email'],
'EmailType' => 'Html',
'dataFields' => array(
 array(
'Key' => 'FULLNAME',
'Value' => $_GET['name_first']." ".$_GET['name_last'] ),
)
);
 $contact = execute_post($postContactUrl, $data);

 $addContactToAddressBookUrl = 'https://apiconnector.com/v2/address-books/' . '123456' . '/contacts';
 $book =  execute_post($addContactToAddressBookUrl, $contact);

 echo "<pre>" . print_r($book, true) . "</pre>";
?>
```

I didn't write it myself but the execute_post is:

```
<?php
//Function to initiate curl, set curl options, execute and return the response
function execute_post($url, $data){
//encode the data as json string
$requestBody = json_encode($data, true);

//initialise curl session
$ch = curl_init();

//curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLAUTH_BASIC, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username' . ':' . 'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: ' . 'application/json' ,'Content-Type: application/json'));

//curl execute and json decode the response
$responseBody = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

//close curl session
curl_close($ch);

return $responseBody;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `execute_post` a function you wrote? If yes, can you edit your post to include it?

Comment: What is the contents of `$contact`?

Comment: I dont think you dont need an array inside array for "dataFields" variable. One more thing in the variable addContactToAddressBookUrl you have used dot(.) To saperate two strings that is not needed.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @MariM - I've added that above

Comment: @DavidWyly $contacts displays the entries in that address book

Comment: @HarshJoshi I know it's an odd way of sending the array but it's the only way dotmailer (the company I'm sending the info to) will accept it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It didn't give any errors about the function at all

Comment: @noobie_woobie Are you sure, that $addContactToAddressBookUrl request recibe the same fields as the first one? Try to make the request directly in the browser using user and pass (we don't have it). It seems that it's a problem with CURL.

Comment: @Ismaestro I tried that and it listed everybody in the address book. When you say it's a CURL problem what do you mean?

Comment: @noobie_woobie well that's what I said a CURL problem... the request was POST not GET...

Comment: @Ismaestro it's amazing what you miss when you panic!! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
```

and it now works perfectly!!